# bind domain class by unique name

Tags: grails, data-binding

My Grails app has the following command object

```
class MyCommand {

    @BindUsing({
        obj, source ->
            User.findByUsername(source.username)
    })
    User user

    // other stuff not relevant to this question
}
```

The request parameters includes a `username` which uniquely identifies the `User`. I've added the `@BindUsing` annotation in order to bind the `user` property of the command object to the corresponding `User` instance. However, after databinding has completed, the `user` field is null, even though the `username` parameter is correct. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you add SQL logging, does the console show any SQL SELECT executed to find the User by username?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think this has anything to do with retention policy, dynamic finders, withTransaction or withSession.  The issue is that the @BindUsing closure is only triggered for the "user" property if there is a request parameter named "user".  The description suggests that there probably isn't one in play in this scenario.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification. This wasn't obvious to me after reading the docs. If I annotate the `user` property with `@BindUsing` then I would expect the closure to be invoked regardless of whether there's a request param named `user`. I understand that when binding at the class level you need a convention to match param names with properties, but in this case, this seems unnecessarily restrictive.

Comment: That was the same assumption which tossed me around to get an answer. I believed binding mechanism has changed regarding the nomenclature to be used in `BindUsing`, but it turns out it has not, as far as naming property field goes. @Don. And yes agree retention policy has nothing to do with it.

Comment: The system currently iterates over request parameters and for each of them that has a corresponding property in the target object data binding is performed.  The request parameter names help decide which properties need binding.  To bind to every property that is marked with BindUsing, one challenge is that we would have to iterate over every property in every class and every property inherited from that class' parent so we can find all of those BindUsing occurrences.  We could come up with a mechanism for helping manage that, but that would be a new feature.  Feel free to file a JIRA.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown thanks again. Am I right in saying that the only way to bind a property from a request param with a different name is to annotate at the class level with `@BindUsing(MyBindingHelper)` and map from the params to the properties in `MyBindingHelper`? It won't actually help in this particular case because I only want to customise the binding of one command class property, but according to the docs "An instance of that class will be used any time a value is bound to a property in the class that this annotation has been applied to"

Comment: I think this is where [`ValueConverter`](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/single.html#dataBinding) comes into picture to customize the data conversion, but I never found out while working on the answer how will it be bound to the command object apart from the fact that it has to be registered as a bean in resources. (Look for Custom Data Converters).

Comment: @dmahapatro I don't think ValueConverter is relevant.  Maybe I misunderstood your comment.  Why do you think it is relevant?

Comment: @Don, No, I don't think you are going to get away with marking the class with BindUsing.  As I said before, the request parameter names are what drives the binder to bind to a property.  We can look at adding something that behaves differently, like an annotation that looks like AnytimeAnythingIsBoundToThisClassDoThis({...}), but no feature like that exists today.

Comment: Based on Don's comment, if only conversion required in the command object is to change a String `username` to a `User` object from the username, then shouldn't `ValueConverter` work as well?

Comment: But then, I believe based on the above conversation I have to stick to the thumb rule that `proeprtyName` should match with param name always, irrespective of the use of BindUsing or a ValueConverter. Please correct me if I am wrong about the statement? @JeffScottBrown

Comment: @dmahapatro You are correct.  The parameter name drives the binding.  If there is no parameter named "foo", then no binding is currently done on a property named "foo".

Comment: There is room here to add new functionality to support use cases like this, but for the use case described it can be very easily made to work either by changing the request parameter name from "username" to "user", or by adding a separate request parameter named "user" and the value could be anything at all since the BindUsing is going to use the value of the "username" request parameter and ignore "user".  "user" is only there to trigger the BindUsing. I think renaming the request parameter is simplest and makes the most sense.

Comment: btw...I don't think source.username is going to work in the closure from the original example.  You will probably need source['username'].

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I also agree with use of `source['username']` but it is kind of misleading in javadocs which says second parameter is a Map (which I think would be the reason for using source.username) whereas the second param is `DataBindingSource` (which is lot like Map) as per javadoc.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Naming the parameter `user` when it really is just a username feels like a bit of a hack. I think there would be some value in the ability to bind a property from a param with a different name, but perhaps not enough to justify the level of effort involved? In my particular case, I'm somewhat reluctant to change the parameter name, because I would then have to hunt through all the JS code that might be accessing this parameter.

Comment: @dmahapatro Thanks for pointing that out.  That is left over from early versions of that code which did use a Map.  See https://github.com/grails/grails-core/commit/1a3c949ebddd5276d96da2def7ce43cd46d120fe.

Comment: @Don If it is a hack and that bothers you then of course don't do it.  I was describing how the system works and how the example can be made to work.

Comment: @Don Will it be useful if you can use the way I mentioned in my deleted answer (I hope you can still see it), that way you do not have to worry about the binding as `getUser()` is what you need ultimately?

Comment: If you do the getUser() thing that @dmahapatro suggested and you retrieve the property more than once, you should cache it on a field so you don't query the database over and over.  

The simplest way to solve this is to do away with all of your BindUsing code and eliminate the need to do the lookup at all.  You can do that by just declaring the domain class property in the command object class and then including a user.id request parameter which will let the framework do the lookup for you.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Created a [pull request](https://github.com/grails/grails-doc/pull/205) for some documentation improvement in grails-doc. I hope it gets merged after review. Thanks again for all the help.